# SQL developer Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

QUESTION: Write a SQL SELECT statement to display the name and address of all departments (except the departments in Dallas) having maximum number of employees. Sort your output in ascending order by department name.

Creating Department Table

```
CREATE TABLE department
( DEPARTMENT_ID         NUMBER(4)       PRIMARY KEY,
DEPARTMENT_NAME     VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,  
ADDRESS             VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL);
```

Populating Department Table

```
INSERT INTO department VALUES(10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(20, 'RESEARCH', 'DALLAS');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(30, 'SALES', 'CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(40, 'IT', 'DALLAS');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(50, 'EXECUTIVE', 'NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(60, 'MARKETING', 'CHICAGO');
COMMIT;
```

Creating Employee Table

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
( EMPLOYEE_ID   NUMBER(4)       PRIMARY KEY,
EMPLOYEE_NAME   VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
JOB         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
MANAGER_ID  NUMBER(4),
HIRE_DATE       DATE            NOT NULL,
SALARY      NUMBER(9, 2)    NOT NULL,
COMMISSION  NUMBER(9, 2),
DEPARTMENT_ID   NUMBER(4) REFERENCES department(DEPARTMENT_ID));
```

Populating Employee Table

```
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7839, 'KING',  'PRESIDENT', NULL, '20-NOV-01', 5000, NULL, 50);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7596, 'JOST',  'VICE PRESIDENT', 7839, '04-MAY-01', 4500, NULL, 50);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7603, 'CLARK', 'VICE PRESIDENT', 7839, '12-JUN-01', 4000, NULL, 50);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7566, 'JONES', 'PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT', 7596, '05-APR-01', 3000, NULL,         10);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7886, 'STEEL', 'PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT', 7566, '08-MAR-03', 2500, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7610, 'WILSON', 'ANALYST', 7596, '03-DEC-01', 3000, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7999, 'WOLFE',  'ANALYST', 7610, '15-FEB-02', 2500, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7944, 'LEE', 'ANALYST', 7610, '04-SEP-06', 2400, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7900, 'FISHER', 'SALESMAN', 7603, '06-DEC-01', 3000, 500, 30);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7921, 'JACKSON', 'SALESMAN', 7900, '25-FEB-05', 2500, 400, 30);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7952, 'LANCASTER', 'SALESMAN',  7900, '06-DEC-06', 2000, 150, 30);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7910, 'SMITH', 'DATABASE ADMINISTRATOR', 7596, '20-DEC-01', 2900,     NULL, 40);
INSERT INTO employee  
VALUES(7788, 'SCOTT', 'PROGRAMMER', 7910, '15-JAN-03', 2500, NULL, 40);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7876, 'ADAMS', 'PROGRAMMER', 7910, '15-JAN-03', 2000, NULL, 40);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(7934, 'MILLER','PROGRAMMER', 7876, '25-JAN-02', 1000, NULL, 40);
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(8000, 'BREWSTER',  'TBA',  NULL,   '22-AUG-13', 2500, NULL, NULL);
COMMIT;
```

The Query That i wrote is below and it works perfectly in finding the maximum number of employees in DALLAS department but I want to eliminate DALLAS and find the other department which has the MAXIMUM number of employee's working in it which is by the data are (CHICAGO and NEW YORK). Can anyone please help me out?

```
SELECT  d.department_id, d.department_name, COUNT(*)
FROM        department d
INNER JOIN  employee e
ON      d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY    d.department_id, d.department_name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = (SELECT  MAX(COUNT(*))
FROM        employee
GROUP BY    department_id) 
ORDER BY    department_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your query:

```
SELECT  d.department_id, d.department_name, COUNT(*)
FROM        department d
INNER JOIN  employee e
ON      d.deptartment_id = e.department_id
where d.address != 'DALLAS'
GROUP BY    d.department_id, d.department_name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = (SELECT  MAX(COUNT(*))
FROM        employee
where department_id not in (select department_id from department where address = 'DALLAS')
GROUP BY    department_id) 
ORDER BY    department_id;
```

;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rank analytic function:

```
select *
from (
    select department_id, department_name, rank() over (order by cnt desc) rnk
    from(
        SELECT  d.department_id, d.department_name, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM        department d
        INNER JOIN  employee e
        ON      d.department_id = e.department_id
        GROUP BY    d.department_id, d.department_name
    )
)
where rnk = 2 --here you may change to what position you want
;
```